# Calculating radius for $\sum\frac{\sin{n^3x}}{n^2}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

Let $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin{n^3x}}{n^2}$ be a series:
a. Find where the series converge pointwise and where uniformally.
b. Does its derivative is continuous?

About A: Using Idea from the comment the absolute value of the series is less then $\frac 1 {n^2}$ so it converges uniformly (M-test) on $\mathbb R$.

About B: I think that if the series converges and the derivative converges uniformly on $[a,b]$, it means the derivative is continuous in $[a,b]$ and it solves b. That means if I knew how to solve A then I'd be able to solve also b. 
Am I right?

Comment: Hint: $\left|\frac{\sin(n^3x)}{n^2}\right|\leq\frac{1}{n^2}$ for any $x$.

Comment: The series given is not a power series because it is not of the form $\sum a_{n}x^{n}$. Moreover since $|\sin n^{3}x| \leq 1$ this series series is uniformly convergent by comparison with series $\sum (1/n^{2})$ for all values of $x$. Buf if we differentiate we obtain a series which does not converge.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh If we differentiate *term by term*.

Comment: My mistake. see my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the definition of the derivative, letting $f(x) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin{n^3x}}{n^2}$, we have $$f'(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin{(n^3 x)}\cos{(n^3 h)} + \cos{(n^3x)}\sin{(n^3 h)}}{n^2} - \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin{(n^3 x)}}{n^2}}{h}$$ by applying the trig identity for $\sin{(x+h)}$.  By comparison to the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{C}{n^2}$ for fixed real $C$ we have that both series in the numerator converge, and by the Weierstrass M-test, in fact uniformly, so that $$f'(x) = \lim_{h\to0} \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin{(n^3x)} \cos{(n^3h)} + \cos{(n^3 x)} \sin{(n^3h)} - \sin{(n^3 x)}}{n^2 h} \; .$$

The uniform convergence of this series (again by the M-test) for $h \ne 0$ allows us to interchange the limit and sum, so that by using the formulae $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin{x}}{x} = 1$$ and $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\cos{x} - 1}{x} = 0$$ we have $$f'(x) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty n \cos{n^3 x}$$ which will only converge for $\cos{n^3 x} = 0$.

The point of confusion here may be why interchanging the limit and sum is justified at the point $h = 0$.  By the M-test we said that the sum was uniformly convergent on $h \in (-\infty , 0 ) \cup (0, \infty)$.  Then we have that $0$ is a limit point of the set on which our sequence is uniformly convergent, and we are allowed to interchange the limit and sum (see Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*, theorem 7.11 on page 149 of the third edition).